# Async double callback in NodeJS loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback, cheerio

I'm going to the next step of my webscraper today !

I'm already looping on an url array with `async` and I would loop again in this callback and wait for its exectution before restart.

I can not figure out how use two callback.

This is my code :

```
   var getWebData = function(url) {
   var data = [];
   async.eachSeries(url, function(urlSingle, cb) {
      request(urlSingle, function(err, resp, body) {
        if (!err) {
          var $ = cheerio.load(body);
          var categoriesURL = [];
            $('.ombre_menu li').each(function(i, element) {
              $(this).find('.nav_sous-menu_bloc li a').each(function(i, element) {
                categoriesURL.push('https://blabla' + $(this).attr('href'));
              })

              // I WANT TO LOOP on the categoriesURL array HERE

                var jsObject = { name : "", description : "", price: "", categorie: "", liter: "", kilo: "", pricePer: "", quantity: "", capacity: "", promotion: "", scrapingDate : "", url: "" };
                data.push(jsObject);
            })
        }
       cb();
      })
   }, function() {
    // this will rum when loop is done
    var json = JSON.stringify(data);
    fs.writeFile('output.json', JSON.stringify(json, null, 4), function(err) {
        console.log('File successfully written!');
     });
   });
}

getWebData(url);
app.listen('8080');
```

Does anyone know how can I do ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made couple of changes in your code:

1. Used `.mapSeries` in place of `.eachSeries`. This way you can get data from iterator function in same order as the input array. Means you'll get [4,9] for input [2,3] to a square function, never [9,4]
2. Broke code into functions so that each function does one specific task
3. Moved categoriesURL processing out of loop 1
4. Returning early. It improves code readability. `if (err) return callback(err);`

---

```
function getWebData(url) {

  // Using .mapSeries in place of .eachSeries as you seem to want to get data from iterator function
  async.mapSeries(url, processUrl, function(err, results) {
    // this will rum when loop is done
    var json = JSON.stringify(results);
    fs.writeFile('output.json', JSON.stringify(json, null, 4), function(err) {
      console.error('Error', err);
      console.log('File successfully written!');
    });
  });
}

function processUrl(url, callback) {
  request(url, function(err, resp, body) {
    if (err) // Return simple cases early; Improves code readability
      return callback(err); // or return callback(); -- if you don't want to send error upwards

    var $ = cheerio.load(body);
    var categoriesURL = [];

    $('.ombre_menu li')
      .each(function(i, element) { // loop 1
        $(this)
          .find('.nav_sous-menu_bloc li a')
          .each(function(i, element) { // loop 2
            categoriesURL.push('https://blablablac' + $(this)
              .attr('href'));
          }) // loop 2 end

      }) // loop 1 end
    // I WANT TO LOOP ON THE categoriesURL ARRAY HERE
    // Using .mapSeries in place of .eachSeries for same above reason
    async.mapSeries(categoriesURL, processCategoryUrl, function(err, results) {
      if (err)
        return callback(err);
      // This function is called after process array categoriesURL

      // Do what you want here then call callback provided to this method
      return callback(null, results);
    })
  })
}

function processCategoryUrl(categoryUrl, callback) {
  // Just process categoryUrl here and call callback with error or results
  return callback();
}

getWebData(url);
app.listen('8080');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Sangharsh for your answer but I'm not sur to know how to use this code...

Comment: Do you have any specific doubts?

Comment: I've tried you code, replaced urlSingle by url (because I had ReferenceError: urlSingle is not defined) and it's look like I have an infinite loop.. @Sangharsh

Comment: Did you call `callback` from `processCategoryUrl ` method? I have put `callback()` for now. Later replace it with your implementation. Try now.

Comment: If it's a success do I have to do return callback() ?

Comment: You *always* have to call `callback`. Callback usually take first argument as error and second as result. It is the only way in async world to tell caller that function has finished.

Comment: Thank you very much @Sangharsh, your code is perfect, I'm editing right now my question because I would use a second request call in my second callback. I hope you know how I can do

Comment: Good to know. Please accept the answer if your query is resolved.

Comment: Can you ask a different question? So that all conversation we had here doesn't become obsolete for viewers. Also, please attach logs/errors when your 2nd request is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested eachSeries. Like this:

```
var getWebData = function(url) {
   var data = [];
   async.eachSeries(url, function(urlSingle, cb) {
      request(urlSingle, function(err, resp, body) {
        if (!err) {
          var $ = cheerio.load(body);
          var categoriesURL = [];
            $('.ombre_menu li').each(function(i, element) {
              $(this).find('.nav_sous-menu_bloc li a').each(function(i, element) {
                categoriesURL.push('https://blablablac' + $(this).attr('href'));
              })
              async.eachSeries(caturl, function(categoriesURL, cb2) {
                      //Do whatever you want to do here
                      cb2();
              },  function() {
                 //You can apply if and else for err an according to that you can set your callback responce here
                 cb();
              };
            })
        }
      })
   }, function() {
    // this will rum when loop is done
    var json = JSON.stringify(data);
    fs.writeFile('output.json', JSON.stringify(json, null, 4), function(err) {
        console.log('File successfully written!');
     });
   });
}

getWebData(url);
app.listen('8080');
```

Comment: Thank you Pankaj for your answer, I don't want to have another function after my second loop. Maybe I can take of the second one and put out the cb() ?